# Download error or resource isn't a valid image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, browser

Getting Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:3000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image) from console?

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from '../Images/logo192.png';

<div>
<img src={Logo} style={{width: '80px', height: '80px'}} alt='react logo' />
</div>
```

Example of image being passed through above.

Comment: What about `<img src={require('../Images/logo192.png')} />`?

Answer (score 14):

Remove the following entry from the `public/manifest.json` file:

```json
{
  "src": "logo192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
},
```

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 8):

Is Logo a valid item?

logo192.png is a png file that is loaded into your project when you use "create-react-app" to start a react project. If you delete this file, react will attempt to search for the resource but will not be able to find it since it was deleted.

To fix the error you have to remove all references to logo192.png in  public/index.html and public/manifest.json.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the following entry from the manifest.json file,

```
{
  "src": "logo192.png",
  "type": "image/png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
}

You may also get error for logo512.png, so delete that too,

    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the image in question is **not corrupted**.
For example, the image may exist and can be downloaded, but the file itself is corrupt.

Open the file in a photo viewer or editor to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this out, but in my case, the file that was delivered (By AWS S3), or so to say, the HTTP response of the `src`-URL, had the MIME Type `application/octet-stream` set, which Next.js did not consider a valid image. Of course, it should be something like `image/png`