# class component with background property invisible

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I have got a class component `Tile` here is its code, its in a separate JSX file:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Tile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    width:"16px",
                    height:"16px",
                    background: `url('${this.props.tiles}') no-repeat
                ${+this.props.x * -16} ${+this.props.y * -16}`
                }}
                className={`tile${this.props.aClass ? ' ' + this.props.aClass : ''}`}
            ></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the `app.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Tile from './components/tile.jsx';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Tile tiles="./assets/Tilemap/tiles_packed.png" x="0" y="0" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

the `Tile` is being rendered but it is invisible, why?

Comment: quotes not required here *url('${this.props.tiles}')...* to *`url(${this.props.tiles})....*

Comment: still not appearing

Comment: looks like the problem is the path, take a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3RWp.png

Comment: So the image is not in that path referred to, check the exact path and try

Comment: no vscode image preview extension shows the expected image, I think the problem is from the compiler

Comment: anything on browser console ? an error or something helpful ??

Comment: no console is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244142/discussion-between-5alidshammout-and-codenewbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to look for after looking at your code

- Import the image as it is not present in public folder to serve.
- Manifest files contain some .png related stuff which needs to be removed for the error in console as per this Q - [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762747/download-error-or-resource-isnt-a-valid-image)
- Don't pass the path of the file from components which are not in same folder hierarchy - why ? It's basic that the path gets changed and resource fails to load which is obvious ...

Modify the parts of code as:

## App.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Tile from './components/tile.jsx';
import tiles_packed from "./assets/Tilemap/tiles_packed.png" // this get's the image and pass it any where you want

function App() {
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Tile tiles= {tiles_packed} x="0" y="0" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

## tile.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Tile extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    "minWidth": '16px', // change styles to view image 
                    "minHeight": '16px',
                    background: `url(${this.props.tiles}) no-repeat
                ${+this.props.x * -16} ${+this.props.y * -16}`,
                }}
                className={`tile${this.props.aClass ? ' ' + this.props.aClass : ''}`}
            ></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: to be sure, importing an image as you did at the `app.jsx` returns a data URL, right?

Comment: For that just log and check ....

Comment: it does, but I thought it was a data URL because I had a bug or a typo

Comment: because when I was using parcel it was returning an edited url